# MS Dynamics CRM 2013 - label of reversed axis

Tags: xml, charts, dynamics-crm

I have a little problem with editing chart in Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Based on tutorial on: https://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/design-options-for-bar-charts-and-top-x-bar-charts/

I made a chart with reversed Axis X. My "problem" is that label for this axis (on the example case - numbers 0.00, 10,000.00, etc.) are on top of the chart. I need this label to be on bottom of my chart. Do you have any ideas how I could do this?

Thank you!

P.S. Do you know any xml schema for MS Dynamics? I have to edit charts, but I don´t know which elements are allowed.

Comment: May be this site helps: https://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/

Comment: I try to find a solution on this website, but unfortunately I did not find one.